# Inserting element in between in C array

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting characters in the middle of char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285587/inserting-characters-in-the-middle-of-char-array)

I need to insert element in between 2 elements in a static array. I have written the following code. Please let me know if we have more efficient code than this.

```
int main()
{
    int a[4];

    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = 20;
    a[2] = 30;

    int x = 15;

    memcpy(a+2,a+1,2);

    a[1] = x;

    printf("%d",a[2]);
}
```

Comment: IIRC, you can't use overlapping memory regions in `memcpy`.

Comment: also, you have to pass the size in *bytes*

Comment: use memmove instead, for the overlapping issue.  Also, you need to specify the length of the move in bytes, so 2 * sizeof(a[0])

Comment: If you move *anything* within 16 bytes, efficiency is no concern. This is going to take about 0.000000001 seconds anyway.

Comment: @Mordachai Thanks . you are right. I have used memmove now.

Comment: @BoPersson ...Hi ...how did you find out the number 16 Bytes? or is that the array size in bytes

Comment: @anup - Yes, you have four `int`'s about 4 bytes each. I think you are worrying about the wrong things. Computers are **fast**.

Comment: @Mark B: `vector` and `deque` aren't available in C.
@anup.stackoverflow: An int may very well be 1 byte, providing CHAR_BIT >= 16.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: I see no reason to believe the OP is limited to C, it wasn't he who removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh. I apologise, I didn't see any C++ tag. :/

Answer (score 1):

You are worrying too much about low level optimizations - the compiler takes care of that.

If believe the most obvious code is also the fastest in this case:

```
a[3] = a[2];
a[2] = a[1];
a[1] = x;
```

You can't get it simpler than that.

---

Here is an example of what the compiler can do when optimizing code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639305/597607

(10 lines of source code turned into 4-5 machine instructions - just let the compiler do its work!).